# My text reader program doesn't print anything

Tags: java, text, io

I made a really simple text reader just to test the mechanic, but it returns nothing and i am clueless! I am not very experienced in Java so it is probably a very simple and stupid mistake! here is the code:

CLASS 1

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class display {


public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    String path = "C:/Test.txt";
    try{
    read ro = new read(path);
    String[] fileData = ro.reader();
    for(int i = 0; i<fileData.length;i++){
        System.out.println(fileData[i]);
    }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("The file specified could not be found!");
    }
        System.exit(0);
}

}
```

CLASS 2

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class read {

private String path;

public read(String file_path){
    path = file_path;
}

public String[] reader() throws IOException{
    FileReader fR = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);

    int nOL = nOLReader();
    String[] textData = new String[nOL];
    for(int i = 0; i < nOL; i++){
        textData[i] = bR.readLine();
    }
    bR.close();
    return textData;

}

int nOLReader()throws IOException{
    FileReader fR = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);
    String cLine = bR.readLine();
    int nOL = 0;
    while(cLine != null){
        nOL++;
    }
    bR.close();

    return nOL;

}

}
```

Comment: Just to mention "Class names start with a capital letter"

Comment: "it returns nothing and i am clueless" well we are also clueless unless you give us some clue what you are getting while running your program.

Comment: Any IO operation in java is probably better done with commons-io (http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) unless you really want to learn how to do it yourself. :)

Comment: String path = "C:/Test.txt";
I think it should be "C:\\Test.txt";

Comment: Please don't process the entire file into a `String[]`. `nOLReader()` reading through the entire file to check it's length is bad; use `ArrayList<String>` instead (dynamic sizing) if you really need store the whole file into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. That's really **a lot of work** you're doing just to read the file. Supposing yourelaly want to stick to your code I'll just point out:

In Class 2,

```
String cLine = bR.readLine();
int nOL = 0;
while(cLine != null) {
    nOL++;
}
```

would run into an infinite loop because you're never reading another line, just the first time is all. So make it something like:

```
String cLine = bR.readLine();
int nOL = 0;
while(cLine != null) {
    nOL++;
    cLine = bR.readLine();
}
```

P.S. Read some simple tutorials to just get the point of I/O in Java. Here's some code [for your job](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/FileRead.java).

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorials?

Comment: @IDCaboutthename, how 'bout learn Java from the masters? Just head down [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You read only one line from file and then check out read value in forever loop (next lines are never read so you never get null inside cLine, so loop never ends). Change your method nOLReader to this (I added cLine = bR.readLine(); in the loop) and it will work:

```
int nOLReader() throws IOException {
    FileReader fR = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);
    String cLine = bR.readLine();
    int nOL = 0;
    while (cLine != null) {
        nOL++;
        cLine = bR.readLine();
    }
    bR.close();
    return nOL;
```

}